# Разбор морфемный слова "пятница"

Tags: морфемный-разбор

помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться как правильно сделать разбор по составу слова "пятница".
В интернете несколько вариантов предлагают, а хочется знать правильный! Один из вариантов "пятн" - корень, "иц" - суффикс, "а" - окончание. А мне самой думалось, что "пятниц"- это корень. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понедельник - от неделя.

Вторник- второй.

Среда - средний.

Четверг - четвертый.

Пятница - от пять, пятый день, пят/ниц/а.

Суббота - шаббат, отдых.

Воскресенье - день бога.

А вот почему пять, какая у этимология у слова пять, это отдельный вопрос, потому что пята и пясть(?) - рука нога. То есть может быть это от слова "последний" или крайний. Также забавно, что нет третьего дня. В английском фрайдей от Фригг (в немецком Фрейтаг) - богини любви и плодородия, тоже и в итальянском-французском и думаю многих других европейских - венерди, от день Венеры, ну Венера тоже богиня любви и плодородия.

в китайском традиционном пятница 金星日 (Jīn xīng rì) - Пятница (День Венеры)

в японском - день металла или золота.

В ведическом индийском - Шукравар, тоже день Венеры.

Короче [вот тут вот много про пятницу](https://www.vaikuntha.ru/blog/vedic_astrology/75.html#:%7E:text=%D0%94%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%3A%20%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80,%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%91%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B) в разных языках.

Про девятидневную неделю славян писать не хочу, найдете сами.

Answer (score 2):

Праильно: пят/ниц/а.

1. Такой разбор дается на многих **[учебных ресурсах:](https://www.antvaset.com/russian-morphemic-dictionary?q=%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)**
2. **Почему так?**

Морфемный разбор здесь **формально-структурный**, без учета истории и этимологии слова. Мы выделяем **узнаваемые морфемы**: корен ***ПЯТ***— (пятый), суффикс существительного ***НИЦ*** и окончание ж. рода ***А***.

Суффикс ***НИЦ*** включает суффикс прилагательного ***Н***, сравнить: *лес  — лес/н/ой — **лес/ник,*** *плен — плен/н/ый — **плен/ниц/а**.*

3. А вот **история и этимология** слова очень интересные:

[Пятница — день любви или день поэтов?](https://dzen.ru/a/YLDpZfjNhEtOQMzD)

[Происхождение слова пятница](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)

[Почему пятница называется пятницей? Причины, фото и видео](https://kipmu.ru/pochemu-pyatnica-nazyvaetsya-pyatnicej/)